# Differences between playing microstakes and higher stakes

Tags: nlhe, cash-game

I have started playing in the internet recently and playing microstakes. The reason is that I wanted to avoid loosing too much in the beginning. Now, after ~15 evenings I am losing a bit more than wining but the difference is not high. But I see that I don't have a big motivation in playing micro. Is there any differences in opponent skills when playing on higher level?

Comment: I think that you are going to have to define "higher level" since that can mean so many different things to different people. Also, it would help if you posted something about your bankroll. The "best" game might not be something that your bankroll is ready for.

Comment: @kazik1616, we all _lose_ (or we were _losing_) in poker sometime, regardless the limits. If you're losing in _micro-stakes_, what makes you think you'll win in higher, more competent games? Remember these guys walked up their way into higher limits so you can pretty much expect _more skilled game_ in higher limits. Continue working on _microstakes_ is definitely the way to go. If you're losing there, why not post your losing hands here so we can help ;)

Answer (score 3):

You state you don't have much motivation playing micro stakes. 
I understand from your statement that what motivates you is the money gains.
They are indeed low at micro stakes. And every poker player would be happy to rank 1st at a tourney with a million dollar gain.
But what should motivate you is the game itself. If you see the game as a part time time job to make extra income you won't succeed. And you'd better learn another skill you can trade part time for money (build websites, sell food, sell home made handcrafts etc...).
If you are passioned about poker and focus on your game, play your A-game, as a result you will win (variance considered), and money will juwt follow.
You could try to play $1000 buy-in games, or $5/$10 CG, you would be playing with players who also lure the big money prizes, but who are very experienced and know what they do, and so going ITM would be much harder. Playing such higher stakes would be even more frustrating for you because you would lose much more money.
If you don't have any motivation playing micro stakes, it is likely you won't have any playing higher stakes.

Comment: Yes, but at the same time, higher stakes means better structures in case of tournaments. Better structure translates to lower variance. Please note that I'm not saying high-stakes, but instead **higher** stakes. @kazik1616 you could move to some medium stakes games for a few weeks, see how things work out. If it doesn't work, you can always step back.

Answer (score 1):

You should play Poker for fun and with what you can easily afford. Harvey's right - don't expect to make significant cash amounts. I personally just like winning, the money comes second!

Answer (score 0):

the players will be better at the higher stakes. holdem has a *huge* variance. do  not move up until you can beat the small game for at least 8bb/100. the higher your win rate is, the lower your variance will be.

good luck.